# Rdlc report missing few charecter of ansi font "sutonnyMj" after upgrading framework 3.5 to 4.61

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, bangla-font

I'm new in programming.

Few part(certain characters) of ansi font "SutonnyMJ" is Missing in report viewer. while exported TO "Word" or "Excel" the missing part is recovered on exported files . Issue exists even after printing using report viewer.If exported to pdf, the issue exists as well.

This scenario happens after conversion from .net framework 3.5 to .net framework 4.6.1 .

Note : This issue is only found on client PC (5 PC Running windows 10).

[This what happening.on left side desired result and right side what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ5nm.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check two things. 1. Increase the height of the textbox to see if the font is just hidden. 2. Check the clients have installed "SutonnyMJ" of not. (PDF is quite tricky when dealing with certain font. You may need to test with different font for it to work.)

Comment: Thanks! I've already checked these two point but no luck . "sutonnyMj" is a ansi font, i tried with similar font all of them showed same issue. only unicode font worked which can't be used in my case because entire data is in varchar(MAX).
Note : 1. Development pc is on Windows 7. and seems to have no problem at all.

Comment: @ShahparanHridoy I once encounter this issue (WebForm) related to a barcode font, my workaround is using a simple WebAPI to convert fonts to image for the particular report as display. (But I think this wouldn't be useful in your case.) I come across this post while googling: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/bangla-sutonnymj-font-problem-in-rdlc-reporting Any of the font in the link post by Sachin Singh works for you?

Comment: @HardcoreGamer thank! , Tried but no luck. only Unicode fonts works properly .